# runtime error string declaration in C++

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-construction, compilation, compiler-errors

Hello i have a code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;  
int main () {
    std::string s="fawwaz"; 
  ...
}
```

then i compiled it with G++ using the gnu gcc online installer i've downloaded from gcc.gnu.org, The compilation runs without any errors and warnings, but when i run, an error appears "program a.exe has stopped working". 
and the program runs without any error. Then i try to compile the original file (without double backslash infront of string declaration) the program compiled and run succesfully.

Whats the solution? Where's the problem? Is they any way to fix my problem so i can compile my program via command line NOT via Microsoft Visual C++ since it would be faster to compile via command line? :D

Thank you

This is the complete code :

```
     #include <cstdio>
     #include <iostream>
     #include <fstream>
     #include <vector>
     #include <string>

     using namespace std;

     void Cetak_Puzzle_Start(){

     }

     int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
     {
        string s;
        ifstream file("input.txt");
        vector<vector<int> > Puzzle_Start;
        vector<vector<int> > Puzzle_Finish;
        int Puzzle_size=0;

        /*
        * RETRIEVE PUZZLE SIZE
        **/
        getline(file,s);
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i)
            Puzzle_size= (Puzzle_size*10) + (int) (s[i]-'0');

        /*
        * Set Zero ukuran 3x3 vector Puzzle start dan Puzzle finish
        **/
        vector<int> vtemp(Puzzle_size,0); 
            for (int i = 0; i < Puzzle_size; ++i)
            {
            Puzzle_Start.push_back(vtemp);
            Puzzle_Finish.push_back(vtemp);
            }

            /*
            * RETRIEVE START STATE 
        **/
        getline(file,s);
        int m=0,n=0; // dummy var for looping only m:pointer baris, n:pointer kolom, 
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i)
            if (n<Puzzle_size){
                if (s[i]=',')
                    n++;
                else if (s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <='9')
                    Puzzle_Start[m][n]= (Puzzle_Start[m][n] * 10) +(int) (s[i]-'0');
                else if (s[i] ='B')
                    Puzzle_Start[m][n]=-1;
             }else{
                 n=0; // Ganti baris
                 m++;
            }

        fclose(stdin);


        /*
        * CETAK PUZZLE
        **/
        // for (int i = 0; i < Puzzle_Start.size(); ++i){
        //  for (int j = 0; j < Puzzle_Start[i].size(); ++j)
        //      printf("%d ",Puzzle_Start[i][j]);
        //  printf("\n");
        // }
        return 0;

     }
```

Comment: You must show us the rest of the program. The error is not withing the lines you are showing. Further you should `#include <string>` if you are using it.

Comment: Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example please : http://sscce.org/

Comment: Does adding `return 0;` to the end of `main` fix the problem?

Comment: @RedX Thats the complete code, sorry for the bad identation

Comment: Where do you declare `kota`? You posted a lot of commented code. Which version does not run? The commented or uncommented one?

Comment: Your error cannot be in the code you've posted, because the code you've posted doesn't compile (`kota` is not declared). Guessing the error is probably in the way you have declared kota, so it's unfortunate you've missed that out. If you want help post the real code, otherwise you'll get people fixing the code you posted not the code you really have. That should be obvious.

Comment: @john sorry i put the wrong full example the last code above is the true code... sorry

Comment: where is the declaration of kota ?

Comment: @fawwaz What values are you entering when you get the crash?

Comment: working fine with my g++ (GCC) 3.4.4 (cygming special, gdc 0.12, using dmd 0.125) on windows 7. What version of gcc are you using ?

Comment: Here It is @bechir
`E:\CPP>g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2>lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-4.6.2/configure -enable->languages=c,c++,ada,fortran,obj
c,obj-c++ --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-dwarf2 --enable-shared --enable-libgo
mp --disable-win32-registry --enable-libstdcxx-debug -enable->version-specific-r
untime-libs --build=mingw32 --prefix=/mingw
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.6.2 (GCC)`

Comment: @john i dont enter any value.. i just read from input.txt, the file input.txt is only consist of two line :
     8
     1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,B

Comment: @john @bechir @georgesl @redxI @beyrem try to debug it via gdb and i get a message like this :

`E:\CPP\n-puzzle>gdb a
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.4
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later ...
(gdb) run
Starting program: E:\CPP\n-puzzle\a.exe
[New Thread 7452.0x22f8]

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x6fc81f62 in libstdc++-6!_ZNSs12_Alloc_hiderC1EPcRKSaIcE ()
   from C:\MinGw\bin\libstdc++-6.dll
(gdb)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the bug,

```
if (s[i]=',')
```

should be

```
if (s[i]==',')
```

and

```
else if (s[i]='B')
```

should be

```
else if (s[i]=='B')
```

Confusing `=` (assignment) and `==` (equality) is a very common error to make

Comment: actually the error not on the string, but the declaration of the string, even when i've change the code as you wrote above...@john